# other users wp theme option is showing I'm try to hide but code is not working

Tags: wordpress

I want to hide the wp theme option except other users but it is still 
showing

[image]

the below code I'm using

```
function twentyfifteen_remove_admin_bar() 
{
if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) 
{
  show_admin_bar(false);
}
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'twentyfifteen_remove_admin_bar');

/*============= custom header code =============*/
```

Comment: Can you try `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');`

Comment: Please, Anyone, help me if got the solution

Comment: Yes, Jaydeep I'm also try this but still showing

Comment: also try to bottom of `fuctions.php` file

Comment: If not working then please try it: `add_action('set_current_user', 'csstricks_hide_admin_bar');
function csstricks_hide_admin_bar() {
  if (!current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
    show_admin_bar(false);
  }
}`

Comment: Yes Try the same code but not worked

Comment: Are you adding this to functions.php or straight into header.php?

Comment: functions.php file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_theme_support( 'admin-bar', 'wpse45721_admin_bar_cb' );
function wpse45721_admin_bar_cb() {
    // What goes here is up to you
}
function hide_admin_bar( $show ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) :
            return false;
        endif;
        return true;
    }
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar' );
```

Comment: 1st one error for return and the second one, not worked same result

Comment: Which theme are you using ?

Comment: I'm using twentyfifteen

Comment: where you wrote these codes? May be your child theme is not working.

Comment: No actually i've modified the whole theme for create a new theme, and also i'm using a theme my login plugin may be that's create a problem

Comment: Try those new codes. I tested that on twenty-fifteen theme as well, just copy all the codes and past it at your function.php